# Prevent multiple api calls

Tags: rx-java, rxjs, reactive-programming, rx-swift, reactivex

How Can I prevent multiple long api calls (e.g. user tap the button several times) without saving state (e.g. saving state to "isLoading" property).

Comment: Maybe use `.take(1)`? Difficult to say without seeing more context.

Comment: Yes, but I need resubscribe again after api call is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are missing requirements here, but assuming you want to avoid making additional calls while there's one executing, until request is finish, you can use `take(1)` with `repeat()` and optionally also `retry()`, `take(1)` will limit emission to the first click, `repeat()` will resubscribe again when `onComplete()` - which ,means the network request done, so you will able to receive single click again and perform request. you can consider also retry() for resubscribing with failure (that will not repeat the request, but will make request available again when clicked)

```
getClicksEvents()
  .take(1)
  .flatMap(aVoid -> getRequestObservable())
  .repeat()
  .retry()
  .subscribe( result -> //do your thing );
```

Comment: That's it! But I am using RxSwift where "repeat" method is missing :X

Comment: @JaSHin are you sure about that? https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxSwift/Observables/Implementations/Repeat.swift you may just need to update your packages. I don't know anything about package management in Swift though.

Comment: well as @AluanHaddad said, this is probably called repeatElement in RxSwift, but I'm not familiar with RxSwift.. (you put the RxJava tag :) so here I am.

Comment: Hehe, I didn't even look at the name of the function. I am not a Java guy BTW. I am a .NET and JavaScript heretic.

Comment: @AluanHaddad  @yosriz repeatElement in RxSwift has different syntax: `Observable.repeatElement(1, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)` It does not appear that it would be the same.

Comment: It seems like this extension of RxSwift has this method https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxSwiftExt#repeatwithbehavior

Answer (score 0):

You can use the debounce function for this:

```
.debounce(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```